# How to convert to jpg and download div containing highchart and dynamically generated html table?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, highcharts

I want to convert and download content of div as jpeg.
That div contains

1.Html table containing dynamically generated content

2.highchart and then

3.Another Html table containing dynamically generated content

i already tried by using two plugins

```
. Html2Canvas
. Canvas2Image
```

with these two plugins i managed to convert and download div to jpeg image but the problem is tables are displaying in image and at the high-chart place blank space of it's corresponding width and height and some values are coming but column are not showing.

Please HelpMe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so hight charts generate svg. So firstly You must convert svg to canvas then convert html2canvas.  The Last Convert Canvas to Image.

I think html2canvas may not work with table tag(ıt does not show). Remove Table tag use div tag.
If You show me the code , I can help.

**Firstly Use canvg.js For Svg To Canvas(You are going to find each svg in your html) because html2canvas not convert svg. Then Your Code is True. .**

Comment: First Thanks for the reply my javascript function for convertind div to jpeg is `<script>
function saveAsJpeg()
{
 html2canvas($(".contentWrapper"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
         var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
          window.open(myImage);
        }
    });
}

</script>`

Comment: Thaks for placing me in right direction.I used canvg.js i achieved what i want.